# Issue with read html in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, html-table

I want to read a table form Wikipedia:

```
import pandas as pd
caption="Edit section: 2019 inequality-adjusted HDI (IHDI) (2020 report)"
df = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_inequality-adjusted_Human_Development_Index',match=caption)
df
```

But I got this errore:
*"ValueError: No tables found matching pattern 'Edit section: 2019 inequality-adjusted HDI (IHDI) (2020 report)'"*

This method worked for table like below table:

```
caption = "Average daily maximum and minimum temperatures for selected cities in Minnesota"

df = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minnesota', match=caption)
df
```

But I get confused for this one, how can I solved this problem?

Comment: I don't think https is supported.

Comment: Thanks for your attention. But this worked for another page, like this:

caption = "Average daily maximum and minimum temperatures for selected cities in Minnesota"

df = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minnesota', match=caption)
df

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple problems here.

`pandas` doesn't support `https`, and there's no such caption that you're looking for.

Try this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests

caption = "Table of countries by IHDI"
df = pd.read_html(
    requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_inequality-adjusted_Human_Development_Index").text,
    match=caption,
)
print(df[0].head())
```

Output:

```
  Rank      Country  ... 2019 estimates (2020 report)[4][5][6]                  
  Rank      Country  ...                      Overall loss (%) Growth since 2010
0    1       Norway  ...                                   6.1             0.021
1    2      Iceland  ...                                   5.8             0.055
2    3  Switzerland  ...                                   6.9             0.015
3    4      Finland  ...                                   5.3             0.040
4    5      Ireland  ...                                   7.3             0.066

[5 rows x 6 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks for your attention. I edited the question. this method worked for me in another page, but I get confused why not worked here?

Comment: Dear @baduker why did you change the caption?

Comment: Because there's no such caption.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_inequality-adjusted_Human_Development_Index')

df[2]
```

Or if you wish to use `match` argument

```
import pandas as pd

caption="Table of countries by IHDI"
df = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_inequality-adjusted_Human_Development_Index',match=caption)

df[0]
```

Returns

[image]